# Is it possible to alter the CPU's cycle count through software?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cycles

In a typical computer system, is it possible to manually change the CPU cycle counter to a specific value? The most obvious method would be to check the counter value and then run NOP or other redundant instructions until the value is as desired, but if the required value is a long distance from the current one this may take an infeasible amount of time - I am looking for something more realistic.

I doubt most architectures would contain an instruction for doing this, but (perhaps because the answer is obvious) I can't find a clear answer elsewhere.

Comment: Some architectures with cycle counters let software modify it.  Which ISA did you have in mind?  x86 for example can set the TSC via MSRs.  But I'm not sure if you have to do that separately on each core, which would make it hard not to de-sync them.

Comment: @PeterCordes My question came about after looking at a MIPS IV system.

Comment: I'd expect every ISA to be different, and even within an ISA, only some implementations might have special ways to set or offset a cycle counter.  Fun fact: AMD-V and Intel VT-x hardware virtualization can both offset and *scale* the TSC for guest VMs, separate from what `rdtsc` reports on the host / hypervisor.  x86's TSC is widely used as a time-source for high-resolution time-of-day stuff; modern x86 runs the TSC at constant frequency independent of core clock cycle frequency changes and halts.